# com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSFMQ6312: An exception occurred in the Java(tm) MQI

Tags: ibm-mq

Getting error when I run my class, I used my cloud mq which is in ibm cloud.

```
    com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSFMQ6312: An exception occurred in the Java(tm) MQI.
The Java(tm) MQI has thrown an exception describing the problem. 
See the linked exception for further information.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:437)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:334)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.nls.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:226)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:8937)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:8307)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl._createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:322)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:242)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.createCommonConnection(MQConnectionFactory.java:6170)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:111)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.createConnection(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:200)
    at PullMessageFromMQ.main(PullMessageFromMQ.java:85)
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2495;AMQ8568: The native JNI library 'mqjbnd64' was not found. For a client installation this is expected. [3=mqjbnd64]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.loadLib(LocalMQ.java:1196)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ$1.run(LocalMQ.java:307)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:691)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.initialise_inner(LocalMQ.java:262)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.initialise(LocalMQ.java:224)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.<init>(LocalMQ.java:1250)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalServer.<init>(LocalServer.java:230)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:437)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.getInstance(JmqiEnvironment.java:765)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.getMQI(JmqiEnvironment.java:699)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:8929)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: mqjbnd64 (Not found in java.library.path)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithPath(ClassLoader.java:1463)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1414)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:619)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.loadLib(LocalMQ.java:1141)
    ... 20 more
```

My code:
I'm connecting to cloud ibm mq and I'm getting com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSFMQ6312:
I need to use selectors to filter messages from mq.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            
    try {
    
                // Connection Factory and Queue details
                MQQueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
                connectionFactory.setHostName(host_name);
                connectionFactory.setPort(port_num);
                connectionFactory.setQueueManager(queue_manager);
                connectionFactory.setChannel(channel);
    
                // Create connection and session
                System.out.println("Connection started");
                Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
                Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
                .....
        }
```

Comment: The error says "See the linked exception for further information." Can you please update your question with the linked exception?

Comment: Its just opening a .class file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this property in MQQueueConnectionFactory, worked for me.

```
connectionFactory.setIntProperty(CommonConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, CommonConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
```